# larevel 5.4 : Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Card' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am new user at laravel framework and using laravel 5.4 .

Its my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Card;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class CardController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $rows = App\Card::all();
        return $rows->all();
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Card' not found
```

Comment: Change this `$rows = App\Card::all();` to `$rows = Card::all();`. You are already importing it via `use App\Card;` at the top

Comment: now show this error :Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all() non static in class App\card

Comment: you need to create the instance

Comment: Do `$rows = Card::all();   return $rows;`

Comment: @HirenGohel still show some error

Comment: try this one public function index()
        {
            $new_r = new Card();
            $rows = $new_r->all(); 
            return $rows;
          
        }

Comment: Have you `Card` model in your `App` directory??

Comment: Could you please show your model file code?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class card extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cards';

}

Comment: @HirenGohel yes of course

Comment: @JYoThI It work true thanks . But why show this error i am using exactly laravel documents ?

Comment: Could you please replace class name card with Card ? and then try as you have written in small letter.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia i do it but yet show some error !

Comment: Instead of return $rows->all(); just check once using dd($rows); and also make sure your model file name should be Card.php inside App directory

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$rows = App\Card::all();` to `$rows = Card::all();`

Because you are using `use App\Card;` to import than class it's unnecessary to do it twice.

Comment: thanks but now show another error :Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all() non static in class App\card

Comment: Does the Card model exist?

Comment: namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class card extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cards';

}

Comment: This probably won't affect it but is your model name lower case?

Comment: @Amin Change `card` to `Card` for the class name. Case sensitivity might be causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with `$rows = Card::get();`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: still show some error ! i am using [This Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models) exactly . But show error !

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`$rows = App\Card::all();`

can be rewritten as

`$rows = Card::all()`

since you have already imported `App\Card`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Card class in your app directory and check the syntax and important implementation such as model , etc.
you can change the name of class and file and create a new model with artisan commend like this : 
`php artisan make:model Card`